# Basic OOPS concept needs clarification

Tags: laravel, oop, namespaces

I am new to OOPS and MVC hence, have confusion about certain concepts which I would like to clarify. As mentioned below in the code, I think, `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;` that is mentioned corresponds to the directory structure and thus means the class `AdminController` is contained in `Admin` folder as is pointed there. But then we have the `use` keyword inorder to use the following namespace. Now the question is why do we use `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`, particular line. What purpose does it serve?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "admin controller";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;` as you stated is used to let laravel know where to access your `AdminController` from.

And your `AdminController` which extends the base `Controller` uses the default classes of base `Controller` so we need to use the `use` specification. `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` is used to let declare that you are going to use the base `Controller` classes in your `AdminController`.

For more info read the official laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers).

Answer (score 2):

**use** usually allows a developer to shorten the namespace.

It *copies* another class from same or different namespace so you can use that class in your code with its class name. You need to write the full namespace if you will use another class without use.

This might help you understand it better. https://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/

Comment: I thought namespaces was introduced in PHP 5.4 but good to know that it was introduced in v5.3. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

***namespaces*** basically group your functions, classes and constants under a particular 'name', which we call a namespace.

Now ***use*** keyword allows a developer to shorten the namespace.***use*** is useful when we are going to call the same function again and again in the same code file or call different functions, constants or classes under a particular namespace.

Comment: want to ask? What if I use `class AdminController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller` and remove `use` statement on the top? Do you think the application will work just fine?

Comment: Probably not, Compiler will complain.check http://rextester.com/XCA94539

Comment: I agree with you, I am getting an exception but why does that happen? I am giving the complete namespace except using `use` keyword then why doesn't the compiler accept that?

Comment: Because it is checking your controller inside current namespace

Comment: You mean this namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Admin`? Why? While extending, I gave it the precise path where to look for then why the error?

Comment: Did you write class with its full namespace.                                         
You should use another class without the “use”, but need to write that class with its full namespace.

Comment: Good information about namespaces : http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: You mean, something like this? `class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller`. That is a syntax error.

Comment: You have App\Http\Controllers\Admin namespace. Inside this namespace, you are defining class called "AdminController". This class should be child of Controller class, which is inside "App\Http\Controllers\". So you need to provide either absolute or relative namespacing.